# Querying on EAV SQL Design

Tags: sql, oracle, entity-attribute-value

I have 3 tables like this.

```
     Entity_Table
|e_id|e_name|e_type  |e_tenant|
|1   | Bob  |  bird  | owner_1|
|2   | Joe  |  cat   | owner_1|
|3   | Joe  |  cat   | owner_2|
```

---

```
     AttributeValue_Table
|av_id|prop_name |prop_value|
|1    | color    | black    |
|2    | color    | white    |
|3    | wing size|   7"     |
|4    | whiskers | long     |
|5    | whiskers | short    |
|6    | random   | anything |
```

---

```
     Entity_AttrVal
     |e_id|av_id|
     | 1  |  1  |
     | 1  |  3  |
     | 2  |  2  |
     | 2  |  5  |
     | 3  |  1  |
     | 3  |  4  |
     | 3  |  6  |
```

What I want to be able to do is something like 'find entity where e_name='Joe' and color=black and whiskers=short.

I can obtain a result set where each row has 1 prop/value, along with the entity information, so querying on one property works. But I need to be able to do arbitrary N properties. How do I do something like this?

Can I build a join table with all properties as columns or something

edit2: Looks like I can do something like this

```
SELECT et.e_id, et.e_name, et.e_type
FROM Entitiy_table et 
LEFT JOIN Entity_AttrVal j  ON et.e_id = j.e_id 
RIGHT JOIN AttributeValue_Table at ON at.av_id = j.av_id
WHERE (av.prop_name='color' AND av.prop_value='white') OR (av.prop_name='whiskers' AND av.prop_value='long')
GROUP BY et.e_id, et.e_name, et.e_type
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'do arbitrary properties'? What is your current query, what does it return, and what do you want it to return?

Comment: You're going to need to join the tables N times to get a result with N attributes.  That is (one) of the reasons that EAV data models are a pain-- when you want to add a new predicate, you have to add another set of joins and that's going to make your query slower and slower.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add a predicate for each name/value combination:

```
  SELECT <whatever you need>
    FROM Entity_Table et
   WHERE et.e_name = 'Joe'
     AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                   FROM AttributeValue_Table avt
                   JOIN Entity_AttrVal ea ON ea.e_id = et.e_id
                  WHERE ea.a_id = avt.av_id
                    AND avt.prop_name = 'color'
                    AND avt.prop_value = 'black')
     AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                   FROM AttributeValue_Table avt
                   JOIN Entity_AttrVal ea ON ea.e_id = et.e_id
                  WHERE ea.a_id = avt.av_id
                    AND avt.prop_name = 'whiskers'
                    AND avt.prop_value = 'short')
```

(I apologize if my Sql Server dialect shines through)

To do an arbitrary number of comparisons, you'd have to generate the SQL and execute it.

As said in a comment, this goes to show that EAV is a pain (an anti-pattern, really), but I know by experience that sometimes there's simply no alternative if we're bound to a relational database.

Comment: I found a similar question here, http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/68679/efficient-query-for-an-advanced-eav-model

Comment: That only seems to filter the attribute *values*, not the value for a specific name. Following that example, you'd find *any* values that are black or short.

Comment: And in the example you added to your question you find entities that have one value OR another value, not AND.

Comment: With having count equal to the number of where clauses, it will only select those entities where both properties matched. I don't know if it is much more efficient than performing N joins

Comment: I don't know if a `GROUP BY` will make it more efficient. I use my proposed method extensively because it is composable. I can easily add/remove predicates and even change them into OR conditions without essentially changing the body of the query. It plays nice with LINQ and predicate builders.

Comment: But it would be interesting to see some benchmark comparisons.