# EAV data in SQL Server

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005, pivot, entity-attribute-value

I have no control over the data or the database structure. I have this EAV type of data where a consultant can speak one or many languages and he can travel to 1 or many countries in Europe and he has many skills indeed.

FYI there are 10 different main categories in my data.

Some consultants speak 10 languages while other speak only one.

The data looks a bit like this

```
 ____________________________________________
| ConsultantID | Category | Value            |
 --------------------------------------------
| 1            | Language | English          |
| 1            | Language | French (fluent)  |
| 1            | Language | Spanish (working)|
| 1            | Country  | Ireland          |
| 1            | Country  | Italy            |
| 1            | Country  | Germany          |
| 1            | Country  | Belgium          |
| 456          | Language | French (working) |
| 456          | Country  | Belgium          |
| 847          | Language | English          |
| 847          | Country  | Belgium          |
 --------------------------------------------
```

I want to list all consultants willing to travel to Belgium and who speak French (*working* or *fluent*). Based on my current example that would be #1 and #456

I wrote the query below which list all values matching a category for a consultant (note this is not dynamic as the number of value in my example is set to 5 max - so already a poor design).

```
SELECT  
    ID, category,
    MAX(CASE seq WHEN 1 THEN value  ELSE '' END ) +
    MAX(CASE seq WHEN 2 THEN ',' + value ELSE '' END )  +
    MAX(CASE seq WHEN 3 THEN ',' + value ELSE '' END )  +
    MAX(CASE seq WHEN 4 THEN ',' + value ELSE '' END ) +
    MAX(CASE seq WHEN 5 THEN ',' + value ELSE '' END )
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         p1.ID, p1.category, p1.value,
         (SELECT COUNT(*) 
          FROM tblWebPracticeInfo p2
          WHERE p2.category = p1.category
            AND p2.ID = P1.ID
            AND p2.value <= p1.value)
     FROM 
         tblWebPracticeInfo p1) D (ID, category, value, seq )
GROUP BY 
    ID, category 
ORDER BY
    ID;
```

I would then need to query this table...

But without even a where clause it takes already 2 seconds to execute

I have something else more basic (but similarly not efficient)

```
select *
from tblWebMemberInfo m 
where 
    m.ID in (select p.id from  tblWebPracticeInfo p 
             where p.category = 'Language' and p.value like 'French%')
    and m.ID in (select p.id from  tblWebPracticeInfo p 
                 where p.category = 'Country' and p.value = 'Belgium')
order by m.ID
```

That's basically where I am. As you can see nothing genius and nothing which is really working.

Can you point me to the right track.

I'm using SQL Server 2005 - v9.00.1

Many thanks in advance for your time & help

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to list the consultants then you can use `exists()`:

```
select p.Id ...
from Person p /* Assuming you have a regular table for people,
                if not, use distinct or group by */
where exists (
    select 1
    from tblWebPracticeInfo l
    where l.Id = p.Id
      and l.Category = 'Language'
      and l.Value = 'French'
      )
  and exists (
    select 1
    from tblWebPracticeInfo c
    where c.Id = p.Id
      and c.Category = 'Country'
      and c.Value = 'Belgium'
      )
```

You could also use aggregation and `having` like so:

```
select ConsultantID
from tblWebMemberInfo m 
where (p.category = 'Language' and p.value like 'French%')
   or (p.category = 'Country' and p.value = 'Belgium')
group by ConsultantID
having count(*) = 2     /* number of conditions to match is 2 */
```

Comment: Thanks SqlZim. Basically one exists function per condition as per this recent post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36432744/querying-on-eav-sql-design